# Enterprise wifi with TLS authentication

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have some questions regarding 802.1x Enterprise wifi with security WPA/WPA2 Enterprise &  TLS Authentication.
Environment : window server 
User machine : ubuntu-16.04
Questions is :

1) Do I need to create User certificate, server certificate and  private key from Linux client machine (I am using Ubuntu 16.04 ) or I need to import these all certifiates from window server where I have configured the wifi router (Radius server)? As I googled, on Windows machine we need to create new certificates every time on every window machine where I want to connect wifi with tls authentication. (correct me if I'm wrong), so do I need to do same with linux machine? If yes/No then how/Why?

2) Please suggest me what is the proper procedure to connect wifi from Linux machine using  window server (radius server + AD)?

Comment: What do you mean by "TLS authentication"? [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is completely unrelated to [Wi-Fi Protected Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access).

Comment: TLS is EAP method in wifi like PEAP .